# PS1 or PROMPT refusing to change in zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt

I enter in zsh:

```
% PS1=">>> "
```

But for some reason, the prompt is still the same:

```
% echo $PS1
%B%F{red}%(?..%? )%f%b%B%F{blue}%n%f%b@%m %B%40<..<%~%<< %b%#
```

Same thing with PROMPT.

It works well in bash and sh. How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have perhaps some pre- or post-command hook that's overwriting your `PS1`?

Comment: I'm not sure what a hook is, I'm gonna check

Comment: Oh-my-zsh isnt installed, neither a zsh theme configuration

Comment: Run `zsh -f`, and then try. It will invoke new shell without looking into any initialization files. If that works then it means some part of your startup file overwrites the prompt (`preexec` and `precmd` functions are the most suspicious here).

Comment: Also interesting is that the `PS1` shown does not produce a single `%` as shown.

Comment: Yes, it works when I use zsh -f. And as you said, the "precmd" function was the one reinitialising my prompt. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The `precmd` function (which is run before displaying a new prompt) was resetting the prompt. All I had to do was:

```
precmd_functions=""
```

(this removes all `precmd` "hook functions")

... and then I was able to change `PS1`. It's possible to change it permanently by adding this line to `~/.zshrc` file.

Comment: maybe the cleanest way is to define env variable `_Z_NO_PROMPT_COMMAND` into your `.zshrc` file, Ref: `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/z/README`