# Mac Terminal has 'pbpaste' on every line

Tags: terminal, macintosh

My mac terminal has 'pbpaste' on every line. I want to know if there is a way to get rid of it.

example:
name@macbook:~$ pbpaste

Comment: `reset`? ......

Comment: Is that somehow part of the shell prompt?  What does `echo $PS1` show?

Comment: I agree with the comment above - maybe the prompt accidentally got set to show pbpaste.

Comment: When I enter echo $PS1 it returns      \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[0;32m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$ pbpaste

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you're using `zsh` (i.e. *probably* running Catalina or Big Sur). The approach for `bash` is similar, but I'm not going to cover it here.

Your *weird prompt* may have been set either from the command line, or in either one of your `zshrc` files (`/etc/zshrc` or `~/.zshrc`).

Try this first:

```bsh
PS1="%n@%m %1~ %# "
```

That should change the prompt immediately. If it doesn't, then [do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498896/286615):

```bsh
precmd_functions=""
PS1="%n@%m %1~ %# "
```

Now you will need to verify that you've not modified `/etc/zshrc` or `~/.zshrc`. You can check this by `source`*ing* the files:

```bsh
. /etc/zshrc
. ~/.zshrc
```

The prompt should not have changed. If it did, and it changed after `. /etc/zshrc` you have modified `/etc/zshrc` file, and you should restore or repair it:

- Open `/etc/zshrc` in your editor, find the current declaration for `PS1`, and edit it to replace the existing `PS1` declaration with this:

  ```
  # Default prompt
  PS1="%n@%m %1~ %# "
  ```

If the prompt changed after `. ~/.zshrc` then it has been modified, and you should restore or repair it. You have choices here:

1. If you're satisfied with the default prompt, you may simply delete the entry for `PS1` in `~/.zshrc`.
2. Of course you don't have to use the default prompt - this is only the a prompt that Apple chose in their infinite wisdom. If you want a prompt *other than* the default (on a recurring basis), you should change `PS1` value here - in `~/.zshrc`.